# Can i know the right procedure of installing Apache Zeppelin on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to install Apache Zeppelin on Kubernetes and its shows running but unable to host the Zeppelin on the port.

i used the reference :http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/03/using-Spark-and-Zeppelin-to-process-Big-Data-on-Kubernetes.html

Comment: Well, add your configurations and the methods your using to show its running. Also, your Host OS is what?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Actually, my kubernetes running on EC2 instances one instance is for Master and another Slave, so how to install Zeppelin on master node instance

Answer (score 1):

To access zeppelin on kubernetes you need to create a service, by default all the ports are closed and you even don't know where zeppelin is installed(if you use multiple servers cluster).
use this service for creating a zeppelin service; https://github.com/2dmitrypavlov/spark4kube/blob/master/spark-zeppelin.yaml
and then got to:

## Zeppelin - you can access spark cluster with zeppelin notebooks:

http://server-ip:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/spark-zeppelin/

If you would like to install Spark and Zeppelin follow this guid; https://github.com/2dmitrypavlov/spark4kube

Comment: i cannot find ./master.sh in the Kube-deploy

Comment: https://github.com/2dmitrypavlov/spark4kube/blob/master/docker/master_ip.sh

Comment: you can use this project pure docker; https://github.com/2dmitrypavlov/sparkDocker

Comment: I am working on kubernetes, so spark4kube tried , but its not working